# How can I generate a random QColor in a thread?

Tags: qt

I want to generate a random QColor in a thread and assign it to the next pixel. Also, this QImage object is going to interface with a signal in the thread. Finally, the interface will print the QImage to the screen.

My goal is to obtain an QImage of 300x300 pixels, each pixel of which consists of random RGB values.

With kind regards!

> 

```
void MyThread::generateRandomColor(int)
{
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        qsrand(time(0));
        QColor(qrand()%255, qrand()%255, qrand()%255);
    }
}
```

Comment: The task, as stated, seems fairly straightforward.  Can you show what you've tried so far (preferably in the form of a [mcve]) and explain the problems encountered.

Comment: why do you seed the random generator inside the loop?

Comment: Confused, I'm a new learner.

Comment: The code you show is odd because you create 256 random QColors, but you don't store any of them anywhere, so they're immediately deleted. I'm not clear what part you need help with though.